# I am Not able to fetch posts from firebase firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to firebase and I was trying to fetch some content posted in firebase firestore database. I have implemented the code, but it unable to fetch posts and only getting refreshed. It shows me a white screen always not any kind of post. It would be helpful if anybody and look into the code and suggest me the best practices to fetch content from the firebase firestore database.

**code for getpost()**

```
public void getAllPosts() {

    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    mFirestore.collection("Posts")
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                        for (final DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                mFirestore.collection("Users")
                                        .document(currentUser.getUid())
                                        .collection("Friends")
                                        .get()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {

                                                if (!querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {

                                                    for (DocumentChange documentChange : querySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()) {
                                                        if (documentChange.getDocument().getId().equals(doc.getDocument().get("userId"))) {

                                                            Post post = doc.getDocument().toObject(Post.class).withId(doc.getDocument().getId());
                                                            mPostsList.add(post);
                                                            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                                            mAdapter_v19.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    if (mPostsList.isEmpty()) {
                                                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                                    }

                                                } else {

                                                    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                                                }

                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                                mPostsRecyclerView.invokeState(EmptyStateRecyclerView.STATE_ERROR);
                                                Log.w("Error", "listen:error", e);
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        }

                    }else{
                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    mPostsRecyclerView.invokeState(EmptyStateRecyclerView.STATE_ERROR);
                    Log.w("Error", "listen:error", e);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Please add your database schema and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: i am not able to get schema for firebase firestore but the collection name what i want to get is "Posts". Posts is the name of collection what i want to get using the above class getAllPosts()